# Less than 48hrs statement in excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, time

I am trying to see if the duration of an email is less than 48hours.

Does anyone know how to input the if statement in excel please?

Example: Email 123, Duration - 39:58:65 (39hrs, 58min, 65sec)

So if(Email123<48hrs,Yes,No)

Thanks

Comment: How can it be 65 seconds?

Comment: how long a ticket has been pending

Comment: Yes, but would 65 seconds tick over to 1:05 minute(s)

Comment: What have you tried?  What has been the actual and expected result?  Where is your Duration stored?  What does it look like in the Formula Bar?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have the duration in one cell represented as `1151:43:33` then you can use this formula:

```
    `=IF(A2<2,"Less than48 hsr.","48 hrs or more")` replace A2 with the cell containing the duration.
```

Time is represented in decimals but when time reaches 24 hrs then becomes a day which is then represented a 1, as such 48:00:00 is represented as 2 (see picture with time and general format).

[image]